# JQuery Live Change FocusOut Events For TextArea Not Firing

Tags: jquery, textarea, live, focusout

cannot seem to find a way to get change or focusout to fire for a input type of textarea, tried a lot of different things and nothing is working thus far... this is my current iteration that does not work either...

I am using latest jquery release.

```
$('input[type="text"],input[type="textarea"]').live(
     'change focusout', function (e) 
    {
        debugger;
        alert('text area');
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Description

Textarea is not an input element, it is a textarea ;) Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/KZF6q/1/)

#### Sample

**Html**

```
<input type="text"/>
<textarea></textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type="text"], textarea').live(
     'keyup focusout', function (e) 
{
    alert(this.tagName);
});
```

#### More Information

- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/KZF6q/1/)

## Update

I don't know if that is what you want but it looks like you want the event fired if the value is changed or the focus is lost. My sample and jsFiddle is updated.